# Magento 2 - change database column type

Tags: magento2, php, database, setup-upgrade, upgradeschema

I need to change the type of the column "value" in the table **catalog_product_entity_varchar** from `varchar(255)` to `varchar(512)`, but I find nothing in the documentation about how to do it, so I copy pasted something together from the code I found.

[image: before]

**app\code\Company\Base\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Base\Setup;

use \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        // Wenn Version kleiner als 1.0.1
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            // Get module table
            $table = $setup->getTable('catalog_product_entity_varchar');
            $connection = $setup->getConnection();

            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($connection->isTableExists($table) == true) {
                
                $connection->modifyColumn(
                    "catalog_product_entity_varchar",
                    'value',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'length' => '512',
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I also increased the version in my module.xml from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1:

**app\code\Company\Base\etc\module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Base" setup_version="1.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Then I executed `bin/magento setup:upgrade` but it changed it to `text` instead of varchar(512) and it removed the comment and the Standard `NULL`:

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Magento replaced the database schema system](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html) and replaced it by a better one. It works now with **etc/db_schema.xml** instead of **Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

**app\code\Company\Ui\etc\db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="catalog_product_entity_varchar" resource="default">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" length="512" name="value" nullable="true" comment="Value"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Then I ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

> **Note**: You can convert your old .php scripts by running `bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1`, this won't work
> if you added custom SQL though. Read the [documentation](http://running%60https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html) for more
> informations.

Comment: Thank you this helped fix my issue.